# Should always pull the monday of the week beginning

Tags: database, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a column called Week beginning. It should retrieve the first monday.

Let us suppose if the report ran  monthly(say Feb 2024)..the week beginning has to show the first monday of the month i.e.,feb5 2024

Likewise select date range ran from mar 1 to mar 21 2024, it should should first monday in this range i.e, on march4

The same has to show for quarterly run. Quarter start first monday.

Pls let me know it has to do in IBM cognos analytics.

We didn't try anything.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You said you didn't try anything, but SO isn't a free coding service. We're here to help you to fix an issue. If you don't have issue, only ideas, we suggest you to try something and come back here when you're blocked, then make a [mre]. You can read more on [ask]

Comment: What kind of data is in your column?  Also I would like you to consider the possibility that sentences like "Likewise select date range ran from mar 1 to mar 21 2024, it should should first monday in this range i.e, on march4" are so at variance with normally understood forms of English that they, subsequently, place on the reader an unreasonable expectation of being magically able to understand whatever you are trying to say.